# Trigger job when artifactory deployment happens

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I want to trigger a jenkins job each time a new file is uploaded to an artifactory folder only if that file is an *.exe. I have tried using URL Trigger so far, but I cannot even trigger the job when any file is uploaded.

This is my url: 
https://artifactory/my_repo/builds/

So, for instance, if someone uploads a folder called v1.8.8 with an *.exe file, the job is triggered.

This is what I have tried so far:
https://artifactory/my_repo/builds/
https://artifactory/my_repo/builds/*/

The poll occurs, but it doesn't detect any change, even when I upload a file directly in the builds folder. What is the proper way to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `/artifactory/api/storage` from your URL.

Full URL in your case should be `https://artifactory/artifactory/api/storage/my_repo/builds/`

Check JFrog official documentation [here](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-trigger-jenkins-builds-when-i-deploy-artifacts/)